# Vertical align image next to ul inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have succesfully managed to vertically align `ul` inside a container `div`.

My question is how to vertically align an `img` next to the vertically aligned `ul`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div style="float: left;">
<img src="logo.png" style="height: 50px;" />
</div>
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
 display: table;
 background: red;
}

#container ul {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#container li {
 display: inline;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1dy3zqk/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with **display: flex** and **align-items: center**

```css
#container {
 background: red;
 display: flex;
 height: 300px;
}
.image{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#container ul {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
}

#container li {
 display: inline;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="image">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFiBE-kc80qZxHO5H7qTc__JvAFpi54QcV8O5qagA8RcRA6661Ag" />
</div>
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do it with `display:flex;`

```css
#container {
 display: table;
 background: red;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
}

#container ul {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#container li {
 display: inline;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" style="height: 50px;" />
</div>
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That hasn't vertically aligned the image, as if the height is decreased to say `40px`, it's aligned to the top.